# American investing in the FTSE 100

Tags: index-fund, international, brexit

Let's say I want to place a bet on the success of an economically independent England.  How would an American investor go about buying into the FTSE 100 (or similar) through ETrade, Vanguard, or Fidelity?

There does not seem to be an easy way to do this.

Comment: As someone in the UK, almost all documents I've seen about (direct) investing in stocks/shares contain words that boil down to "_If you're a US person... go away" :-). I suspect (but not currently sure enough to make an answer) that this is in large part down to rules/regulations (FINBAR??) from the SEC/IRS that would impose too-complicated-to-bother-with reporting / regulatory requirements should such products be offered to US citizens... slightly similar (although in reverse) to [Buying an US ETF from Europe using Interactive Brokers](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/112871/35567).

Comment: The justETF page [Top FTSE 100 ETFs](https://www.justetf.com/uk/how-to/ftse-100-etfs.html) may help (although I don't know that they are available to the US).

Comment: I don't know anything about them but ETFdb lists VGK (Vanguard) and FLGB (Franklin) as US ETFs that track the FTSE.

Comment: @BobBaerker That is a good idea. You should post it as an answer to the question.

Comment: Nitpicks: 1) England has just about 0 chance to be independent, you likely mean the UK, or Britain depending on the terms of brexit. 2) Brexit is still very much up in the air so it might not happen.

Comment: Agree on both points.  As an American the whole England-Brittan-United Kindom thing is interesting hut is not something I've ever had to really deal with or understand.  I trusted that folks would figure it out.  As far as Brexit, there is s fair chance that the government will balk.  I just want to know what to do in case BoJo is successful.